# applicationContext.xml not found in Spring application with NetBeans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, netbeans-8

I'm new to Spring.
While running a simple application I'm getting this exception. I tried some solutions present on SO, but none worked for me.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Full Trace:

```
run: Jul 25, 2015 4:05:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@750d7792: startup date [Sat Jul 25 16:05:21 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy Jul 25, 2015 4:05:21 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)  at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)   at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)    at com.pra.TestSpringProject.main(TestSpringProject.java:14) Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist  at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)  ... 13 more Java Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

[image]

Comment: Show your Project structure please.

Comment: @Jens, added structure.. Please see

Comment: I just tried to resolve by adding applicationContext.xml in my package

Comment: Add it directly under 'Source Packages'

Comment: @TheCodingFrog, It is working .. Thanks :)

Comment: I have add it as answer. Since it's working you can accept it as as answer.

Comment: You have to add the application.xml to src/main/ressource in your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it directly under `Source Packages`.